# Error while using os.system in python

Tags: bash, python-2.7

I am using os.system to run a bash command from python:

```
os.system("`cat SPheno.spc.Stueckelberg | grep \"# hh_1\" | grep -v
DECAY | sed 's/\(.*\) 25 \(.*\)\# hh_1/\2/g'`")
```

I get the error: sh: 1: : not found 32512.

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Amin

Comment: why is your command wrapped in backticks?

Comment: use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module. From that doc: "This module intends to replace several older modules and functions:

`os.system`
`os.spawn*`..."

Comment: thought: does the command run on bash without using python?

Comment: @WillBarnwell The backticks work well used in command line.

Comment: @downshift Yes the command works on bash but when I try to run it via python it produces an error.

Comment: for more information about the error: http://shortrecipes.blogspot.com/2008/11/python-ossystem-return-32512.html Perhaps there is a part of the command that your OS does not recognize

Comment: Thanks @downshift but that didn't help solve the issue.

Comment: I must say that removing the "sed" line and the backticks gives the correct output but I want sed to strip away the unwanted pieces from the line.

Comment: @Amin What does it output if you include `sed` but leave out the backticks? If that doesn't fix it, we'll really need to know what's in the file (or at least the line that includes "# hh_1") to get any real idea what's going on.

Comment: the error is being caused by the backticks. What your code says is this: execute the code inside the backticks, then send the output of that to the os.system command. So, the output of the code in backticks is 1 and effective what you are doing is this:  os.system("1"). Since 1 is not a valid command, you are getting the error